# Initialize vector<Temp> myVector(10);

Tags: c++, vector, initialization

According to Absolute c++ books:

> ```
> vector<AClass> records(20); // vector consctructer uses the
>                              // default constructor for AClass to initialize 20 elements.
> ```

temp.h

```
#ifndef TEMP_H
#define TEMP_H

class Temp {
public:
    Temp();
    static int b;
};
#endif /* TEMP_H */
```

temp.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "temp.h"

using namespace std;

int Temp::b=9; // static value for control 

Temp::Temp(){
    cout<<"Initialize";
    ++b;
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include "temp.h"

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    vector<Temp> a(10); // 10 elements

    cout<<Temp::b;

    return 0;
}
```

And my result's : 
   `Initialize10;`

As you can see just one times constuctor called. Why its happened? I'm confused.

Comment: What compiler and what options are you using?

Comment: You're implicitly calling the constructor of `Temp` 10 times by creating a vector of 10 items.  Also, if you really want to track object creation, you need to write a user-defined copy constructor.

Comment: I compiled on netbeans 8.1 for windows.I didn't change any option on compiler. Everythings standart.

Comment: `int Temp::b=9;` Could you make this example more confusing please?

Comment: NetBeans is an IDE, not a compiler.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I think static b should increase 10 times and final b should be 19.

Comment: @HaSaNMen  Creating objects are not only done by default constructor.  You have copy construction, and again, you didn't write a user-defined copy constructor to discover where those 9 other objects are coming from.

Comment: @HaSaNMen See here: http://ideone.com/NuyJeF  and here: http://ideone.com/Fxo619  I used a C++ 03 standard compiler to show you what you're missing in your tests.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That `vector` constructor behaves differently in C++03 and C++11 (and later).

In C++03, it inserts 10 copies of a default-constructed `Temp` object: the default constructor is called once and the copy constructor (which you didn't instrument) is called 10 times.

In C++11, it inserts 10 default-constructed `Temp` objects.

Comment: You're right. I add copy constructer and now working fine. I undestand the problem. Thank's.